# JWT авторизация возвращает 403 ошибку вместо 401

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, jwt

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста по данной ситуации.

Бэк на Django Rest, фронт на Vue.

Может я чего-то не до конца понимаю, но при истечении времени jwt токена мне возвращается 403 ошибка (нет доступа), хотя по моему должна возвращаться 401 (не авторизован), приходится ловить 403 для обновления токена, я боюсь что в некоторых случаях могут возникнуть проблемы, тк в некоторых эндпоинтах я возвращаю 403 ошибку если пользователь не имеет доступа, с фронта конечно он вряд ли туда попадет, но все же, если попадет, то будут проблемы. Скину сюда настройки DRF и JWT. Пока я не понимаю где искать проблему, но уверен что она на бэке. Повторюсь, может я что-то не понимаю и так и должно быть, но получается как то не логично)

```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
  }
```

JWT:

```
   SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
  }
```

PS Если описание проблемы не совсем понятно и нужен еще код, добавлю!

Заране спасибо за ответы!

---

Добавлю к обсуждению - только что через Postman попробовал сделать запрос без токена, все равно вернулась 403...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте
rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication
поставить после
rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication в кортеже

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в бэкенд части, в этом файле:

```
rest_framework_simplejwt/exceptions.py
```

скорее всего отдаётся не `status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED`, a `status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Проверил, спасибо. К сожалению там возвращается 401..

Comment: А вы можете выгрузить код проекта на гитхаб, так можно будет хоть код весь посмотреть.

Comment: Можно тут как нибудь в личные сообщения скинуть?

Comment: В профиле указал ник телеграма, если есть возможность, напишите, скину ссылку на гитхаб

Comment: Написал вам в телеграме

Answer (score 0):

На первое время было принято решение поставить костыль в коде и написать middleware для перехвата 403 ошибки в случае обновления токена.

```py
class NoAuthorisationJWT:
""" Перехват непонятного статус-кода 403 при отсутствии авторизации и корректировка на нужный 401
"""
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self._get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = self._get_response(request)
    try:
        if response.data['detail'] == 'Given token not valid for any token type':
            response.status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    except Exception:
        # Другие запросы имеют иную структуру, поэтому исключения игнорируем
        pass

    return response
```

Comment: Если вы хотите добавить код к вопросу, то следует отредактировать сам вопрос.